# Updated NODE to Latest Version*20 but still "node -v" NODE showing the older version*18

Tags: node.js, nvm

Even if the NVM updates/upgrades are successful, the NODE still shows the old version.

NODE has been updated to the latest version*20, but the command "node -v" still shows the old version*18 to check the NODE version currently in use.

I used the command "nvm alias default 20.8.0" to change node default version*v18.18.0 to *v20.8.0 but still NODE shows the old version in use.

I am looking for a solution to solve the above problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using the below commands (via CLI), which enables server to use the Updated NODE Version*20

```
nvm use 20.8.0
```

Output (Summary)    =>  Now using node v20.8.0 (npm v10.1.0)

Now check and confirm the default NODE version got updated sucessfully using the below commands (via CLI), from version*v18.18.0 to *v20.8.0

```
node -v
```

Output (Summary)     => Node Version *v20.8.0